# Databricks - module 'mlflow.sklearn' has no attribute 'eval_and_log_metrics'

Tags: scikit-learn, databricks, mlflow

working in Databricks. Submitting a job using dbx. When I submit the code to the job, I get the following error.

```
AttributeError: module 'mlflow.sklearn' has no attribute 'eval_and_log_metrics'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
File <command--1>:13
     10 del sys
     12 with open(filename, "rb") as f:
---> 13   exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'))

File /tmp/tmpzkz203ow.py:64
     62 if __name__ == "__main__":
     63     job = ModelTrainJob()
---> 64     job.launch()

File /tmp/tmpzkz203ow.py:58, in ModelTrainJob.launch(self)
     48 _logger.info(f'Running model-train pipeline in {self.env_vars["env"]} environment')
     49 cfg = ModelTrainConfig(
     50     mlflow_tracking_cfg=self._get_mlflow_tracking_cfg(),
     51     feature_store_table_cfg=self._get_feature_store_table_cfg(),
   (...)
     56     env_vars=self.env_vars,
     57 )
---> 58 ModelTrain(cfg).run()
     59 _logger.info("ModelTrainJob job finished!")

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/customer_churn/objects/model_train.py:231, in ModelTrain.run(self)
    229 _logger.info("==========Model Evaluation==========")
    230 _logger.info("Evaluating and logging metrics")
--> 231 test_metrics = mlflow.sklearn.eval_and_log_metrics(model, X_test, y_test, prefix="test_")
    232 print(pd.DataFrame(test_metrics, index=[0]))
    234 # Register model to MLflow Model Registry if provided

AttributeError: module 'mlflow.sklearn' has no attribute 'eval_and_log_metrics'
```

I see eval_and_log_metrics function is available in ML flow.
https://mlflow.org/docs/1.30.0/python_api/mlflow.sklearn.html

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question, so posting in case anyone else runs into the same issue.

The eval_and_log_metric function was available in MLflow 1.30, but has been removed in MLflow >2.0 https://mlflow.org/docs/2.0.1/python_api/mlflow.sklearn.html

In the setup.py file, I forced a MLflow install of 1.30 and didn't change my code. This solved my issue.